# Python - No attribute 'svc' error

Tags: python, python-3.x, scikit-learn

I have a small script that uses `svm` from `sklearn`. I am using Python 3.6 32 bit. The script:

```
import pandas as pd
from sklearn import svm

### Read the CSV ###
df = pd.read_csv('C:/Users/saeed/Downloads/SalesJan2009.csv')
df

from sklearn.cross_validation import train_test_split

train, test = train_test_split(df, train_size = 0.8)
train
test



svc = svm.SVC()
model = svm.svc(kernel='linear', C=1, gamma=1)
```

When I run it, it returns with this error:

```
AttributeError: module 'sklearn.svm' has no attribute 'svc'
```

I don't understand how to fix this. Any ideas?

Comment: @CoryMadden: Huh; looks pretty close to being an _exact_ duplicate. At a guess, this is coming from a poorly written tutorial somewhere online.

Answer (score 0):

you should instantiate SVC with the parameters:

```
model = svm.SVC(kernel='linear', C=1, gamma=1)
```

After that, you can fit a model with your data

Ref.: http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.svm.SVC.html

Answer (score 0):

You need to use **capitals.**

**The new code should be the following:**

```
import pandas as pd
from sklearn import svm

### Read the CSV ###
df = pd.read_csv('C:/Users/saeed/Downloads/SalesJan2009.csv')
df

from sklearn.cross_validation import train_test_split

train, test = train_test_split(df, train_size = 0.8)
train
test

model = svm.SVC(kernel='linear', C=1, gamma=1)
```